# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Prueba3'

Tags: python, django

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]para verificar conexion a una base de datos de Maria DB intento ejecutar en la Terminal de Visual Studio Code el archivo pruebadb.py que se encuentra en la carpeta con nombre Prueba3 (carpeta creada por defecto en la creacion del proyecto y que lleva el mismo nombre de este), pero me sale el error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Prueba3'.

Codigo del archivo

```py
from settings import *
import pymysql
from django.conf import settings

conexion=pymysql.connect('hotelsys_1001')
cursor = conexion.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ro_rooms(number,id_ad_rooms_type,id_ad_rooms_status) VALUES(1020,1,1)")
conexion.commit()
print ("Registro almacenado exitosamente")
conexion.close()
```

Este es el mensaje de error en consola

```
PS D:\Proyectos\Prueba3\prueba3> py pruebabd.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Proyectos\Prueba3\prueba3\pruebabd.py", line 5, in <module>
    conexion=pymysql.connect('hotelsys_1001')
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: No pongas los *imports* en una sola línea, cada `import` en una línea distinta. Y.... en el código que muestras no se ve el `import prueba3` y tampoco has añadido la estructura o arbol de tu proyecto

Comment: Hola Christian, ya corregi el tema de los imports en cada linea y puse el import prueba3, y persiste el inconveniente; disculpas por lo del arbol del proyecto, pero pense que habia cargado.

Comment: Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/482809/edit) tu pregunta añadiendo eso por favor

Comment: También modifica el código de aquí

Comment: Por cierto, al encontrarte ya en el directorio donde se encuentra el archivo solo debes hacer `from settings import ..` si haces `from Prueba3.settings import...` python buscará una carpeta llamada `Prueba3` y como no la hay lanza el error

Comment: El título no encaja con el problema mostrado

Comment: el error dice claramente que le estas pasando un solo argumento y espera 2 aunque en realidad espera mas, ya que son objetos aqui un ejemplo:  `pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='user',password='passwd',database='db',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)` [documentacion pymsql](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html)

Comment: Comprendo Christian y muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pero al realizar las correcciones que me indico se me genero este nuevo error

Comment: Bryro, en el archivo setting.py ya tengo configurados los datos de conexion en la DATABASE default